# Part of the ListView being cut-off

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf

I am using this code to distribute even width to all columns, but it still passes through its parent, producing a horizontal scroll

```
private void listView_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var newWidth = listView.ActualWidth / gridView.Columns.Count;
        foreach (var column in gridView.Columns)
        {
            column.Width = newWidth;
        }
    }
```

[image: WPF List View]

Because of this, when I convert it to a PDF file, it produces something like this:

[image: PDF List View]

I already adjusted the list view's width the same as an A4 paper.Oh, and the paper is of the Letter size, that's why there is a white spacing to the right

```
public void CreateMyWPFControlReport()
    {

        FixedDocument fixedDoc = new FixedDocument();
        PageContent pageContent = new PageContent();
        FixedPage fixedPage = new FixedPage();
        someGrid.Children.Remove(listView);
        listView.Width = 96 * 8.267;
        //Create first page of document
        fixedPage.Children.Add(listView);
        ((System.Windows.Markup.IAddChild)pageContent).AddChild(fixedPage);
        fixedDoc.Pages.Add(pageContent);
        //Create any other required pages here


        MemoryStream lMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        {
            Package package = Package.Open(lMemoryStream, FileMode.Create);
            XpsDocument xpsd = new XpsDocument(package);
            XpsDocumentWriter xw = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(xpsd);
            xw.Write(fixedDoc);
            xpsd.Close();
            package.Close();
        }

        var pdfXpsDoc = PdfSharp.Xps.XpsModel.XpsDocument.Open(lMemoryStream);
        try
        {
            PdfSharp.Xps.XpsConverter.Convert(pdfXpsDoc, @"C:/nye/affaf.pdf", 0);
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("File is open, please close first");
        }
    }
```

What causes this behavior? Although I can reduce the width little by little, that would be a little time-consuming. Or do I need to do it?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with Listviews but either subtract 2 from actualwidth and divide that or try setting the width of all columns to *.

Comment: Guess I really need some trial and error to solve this

Comment: Reason for your horizontal scroll bar is either rounding 'error' or that there are borders involved. You could also inspect the window during runtime. Visual studio 2015 and 2017 have an in-build feature for that.

Comment: The black bar one?

Comment: Not necessarily. Borders are not always visible but act as a container for another control. In any case, inspect the listview during runtime and take a look at the columns and if they are wrapped in container controls that have a width or thickness greater 0.

Comment: Check `System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation` there you have all the sizes for controls, borders and so on, I think you must subtract the borders from the column width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the horizonal scroll, try setting the `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` (attached property) of the ListView in your XAML.

```
 <ListView x:Name="listView" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ... >
    ...       
 </ListView>
```

To distribute even width to all GridViewColumns of your ListView, you can use a value converter. WPF will automatically call the Convert() method of the converter whenever it needs to reevaluate the width of a GridViewColumn (like after a resize of the application).

```
public class ListViewEvenColumnWidthConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public int ColumnCount { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return 0;

        double width = (double)value;

        if (width == 0)
            return 0;

        return width / ColumnCount;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException(); 
    }
}
```

To use this value converter in your XAML, add it as a resource. The `value` passed in to the converters Convert() method, is the width of the entire listview. We want to return that value divided by the number of columns. For example with four GridViewColumns;

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:ListViewEvenColumnWidthConverter x:Key="EvenColumnWidthConverter" ColumnCount="4" />
</Window.Resources>

...

 <ListView x:Name="listView" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
     <ListView.View>
         <GridView>
             <GridViewColumn Header="Date" Width="{Binding ElementName=listView, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource EvenColumnWidthConverter}}" />
             <GridViewColumn Header="Supplier" Width="{Binding ElementName=listView, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource EvenColumnWidthConverter}}" />
             <GridViewColumn Header="Product" Width="{Binding ElementName=listView, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource EvenColumnWidthConverter}}" />
             <GridViewColumn Header="Quantity Sold" Width="{Binding ElementName=listView, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource EvenColumnWidthConverter}}" />
             ...
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
        Test Text
</ListView>
```

Comment: It still produces a horizontal scrollbar, although `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` really removed the scroll bar.

Comment: Never mind, it worked. Forgot to remove the old converter

Comment: Glad i could help.